# How do I make/convert my python app into an Rshiny app? Its a brainteaser! Unable to find what change UI needs in R

Tags: python, r, dplyr, shiny, reticulate

i am new to R and trying to understand Rshiny to build UIs. I am trying to create a UI for my python app that transcribes mulitple wav files. There are two parts below, first my python app and the second my shiny app in R which uses reticulate to call my transcribe.py app. For some reason though, i do not receive any output.

My Python app works perfectly and does NOT need code review.However, the Rshiny app does not execute the python app correctly to produce the desired result. The objective is to let the user transcribe the files from the UI and decide if they want to download the csv.

I have a python app for transcribing files called transcribe.py-

```
import os
import json
import time
# import threading
from pathlib import Path

import concurrent.futures

# from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

import pandas as pd

# Replace with your api key.
my_api_key = "abc123"

# You can add a directory path to Path() if you want to run
# the project from a different folder at some point.
directory = Path().absolute()


authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(my_api_key)

service = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=authenticator)
service.set_service_url('https://api.us-east.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com')
# I used this URL.
# service.set_service_url('https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api') 


models = service.list_models().get_result()
#print(json.dumps(models, indent=2))

model = service.get_model('en-US_BroadbandModel').get_result()
#print(json.dumps(model, indent=2))



# get data to a csv
########################RUN THIS PART SECOND#####################################


def process_data(json_data, output_path):

    print(f"Processing: {output_path.stem}")

    cols = ["transcript", "confidence"]

    dfdata = [[t[cols[0]], t[cols[1]]] for r in json_data.get('results') for t in r.get("alternatives")]

    df0 = pd.DataFrame(data = dfdata, columns = cols)

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(json_data.get("speaker_labels")).drop(["final", "confidence"], axis=1)


    # test3 = pd.concat([df0, df1], axis=1)
    test3 = pd.merge(df0, df1, left_index = True, right_index = True)


    # sentiment
    print(f"Getting sentiment for: {output_path.stem}")
    transcript = test3["transcript"]
    transcript.dropna(inplace=True)

    analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    text = transcript
    scores = [analyzer.polarity_scores(txt) for txt in text]

    # data = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ["Text"])
    data = transcript.to_frame(name="Text")
    data2 = pd.DataFrame(scores)


    # final_dataset= pd.concat([data, data2], axis=1)
    final_dataset = pd.merge(data, data2, left_index = True, right_index = True)

    # test4 = pd.concat([test3, final_dataset], axis=1)
    test4 = pd.merge(test3, final_dataset, left_index = True, right_index = True)

    test4.drop("Text", axis=1, inplace=True)

    test4.rename(columns = {
            "neg": "Negative",
            "pos": "Positive",
            "neu": "Neutral",
            }, inplace=True)

    # This is the name of the output csv file
    test4.to_csv(output_path, index = False)


def process_audio_file(filename, output_type = "csv"):

    audio_file_path = directory.joinpath(filename)

    # Update output path to consider `output_type` parameter.
    out_path = directory.joinpath(f"{audio_file_path.stem}.{output_type}")

    print(f"Current file: '{filename}'")

    with open(audio_file_path, "rb") as audio_file:
        data = service.recognize(
                audio = audio_file,
                speaker_labels = True,
                content_type = "audio/wav",
                inactivity_timeout = -1,
                model = "en-US_NarrowbandModel",
                continuous = True,
            ).get_result()

    print(f"Speech-to-text complete for: '{filename}'")

    # Return data and output path as collection.
    return [data, out_path]


def main():
    print("Running main()...")

    # Default num. workers == min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4)
    n_workers = os.cpu_count() + 2

    # Create generator for all .wav files in folder (and subfolders).
    file_gen = directory.glob("**/*.wav")

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = n_workers) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(process_audio_file, f) for f in file_gen}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            pkg = future.result()
            process_data(*pkg)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(f"Program to process audio files has started.")

    t_start = time.perf_counter()

    main()

    t_stop = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Done! Processing completed in {t_stop - t_start} seconds.")
```

In Rstudio, I tried -

**R.UI file**

```
library(shiny)
library(reticulate) # for reading Python code
library(dplyr)
library(stringr) 
library(formattable) # for adding color to tables
library(shinybusy) # for busy bar
library(DT) # for dataTableOutput

use_python("/usr/lib/python3")

ui <- fluidPage(
  add_busy_bar(color = "#5d98ff"),
  fileInput("wavFile", "SELECT .WAV FILE", accept = ".wav"),
  uiOutput("downloadData"),
  dataTableOutput("transcript"),
  
)
```

**R.Server file**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # .WAV File Selector ------------------------------------------------------
  
  file <- reactive({
    file <- input$wavFile # Get file from user input
    gsub("\\\\","/",file$datapath) # Access the file path. Convert back slashes to forward slashes.
  })
  
  
  # Transcribe and Clean ----------------------------------------------------
  
  transcript <- reactive({
    
    req(input$wavFile) # Require a file before proceeding
    
    source_python('transcribe.py') # Load the Python function           # COMMENT LINE OUT WHEN TESTING NON-TRANSCRIPTION FUNCTIONALITY
    transcript <- data.frame(transcribe(file())) # Transcribe the file  # COMMENT LINE OUT WHEN TESTING NON-TRANSCRIPTION FUNCTIONALITY
    # load('transcript.rdata') # Loads a dummy transcript               # UNCOMMENT LINE OUT WHEN TESTING NON-TRANSCRIPTION FUNCTIONALITY
    
    transcript$transcript <- unlist(transcript$transcript) # Transcript field comes in as a list. Unlist it.
    transcript <- transcript[which(!(is.na(transcript$confidence))),] # Remove empty lines
    names(transcript) <- str_to_title(names(transcript)) # Capitalize column headers
    
    transcript # Return the transcript
    
  })
  
  
  # Use a server-side download button ---------------------------------------
  
  # ...so that the download button only appears after transcription
  
  output$downloadData <- renderUI({
    req(transcript())
    downloadButton("handleDownload","Download CSV")
  })
  
  output$handleDownload <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('Transcript ',Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(transcript(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
  
  # Transcript table --------------------------------------------------------
  
  output$transcript <- renderDataTable({ 
    as.datatable(formattable(
      transcript() %>%
        select(Transcript,
               Confidence,
               Negative,
               Positive
        ),
      list(Confidence = color_tile('#ffffff','#a2b3c8'),
           Negative = color_tile('#ffffff', '#e74446'),
           Positive = color_tile('#ffffff', "#499650")
      )
    ), rownames = FALSE, options =list(paging = FALSE)
    )
  })
  
  
  # END ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  
}
```

Comment: Try `req(input$wavFile)` in `file <- reactive({...})`

Comment: You would probably increase the chances to get an answer if you could reproduce the problem without the need to create a Watson API key. Could you supply a fake `transcript()` just returning the expected result after some `Sys.sleep(...)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In shiny, you need to pass argument properly in python script. An easy way around is to define a function in a python script and call that function in shiny.

Here is your modified python script (edited process_data function and added run_script function) -

```
import os
import json
import time
# import threading
from pathlib import Path

import concurrent.futures

# from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

import pandas as pd

# Replace with your api key.
my_api_key = "api_key"

# You can add a directory path to Path() if you want to run
# the project from a different folder at some point.
directory = Path().absolute()


authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(my_api_key)

service = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=authenticator)
service.set_service_url('https://api.us-east.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com')
# I used this URL.
# service.set_service_url('https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api') 


models = service.list_models().get_result()
#print(json.dumps(models, indent=2))

model = service.get_model('en-US_BroadbandModel').get_result()
#print(json.dumps(model, indent=2))



# get data to a csv
########################RUN THIS PART SECOND#####################################


def process_data(json_data):

    #print(f"Processing: {output_path.stem}")

    cols = ["transcript", "confidence"]

    dfdata = [[t[cols[0]], t[cols[1]]] for r in json_data.get('results') for t in r.get("alternatives")]

    df0 = pd.DataFrame(data = dfdata, columns = cols)

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(json_data.get("speaker_labels")).drop(["final", "confidence"], axis=1)


    # test3 = pd.concat([df0, df1], axis=1)
    test3 = pd.merge(df0, df1, left_index = True, right_index = True)


    # sentiment
    #print(f"Getting sentiment for: {output_path.stem}")
    transcript = test3["transcript"]
    transcript.dropna(inplace=True)

    analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    text = transcript
    scores = [analyzer.polarity_scores(txt) for txt in text]

    # data = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ["Text"])
    data = transcript.to_frame(name="Text")
    data2 = pd.DataFrame(scores)


    # final_dataset= pd.concat([data, data2], axis=1)
    final_dataset = pd.merge(data, data2, left_index = True, right_index = True)

    # test4 = pd.concat([test3, final_dataset], axis=1)
    test4 = pd.merge(test3, final_dataset, left_index = True, right_index = True)

    test4.drop("Text", axis=1, inplace=True)

    test4.rename(columns = {
            "neg": "Negative",
            "pos": "Positive",
            "neu": "Neutral",
            }, inplace=True)

    # This is the name of the output csv file
    # test4.to_csv(output_path, index = False)
    return(test4)


def process_audio_file(filename, output_type = "csv"):

    audio_file_path = directory.joinpath(filename)

    # Update output path to consider `output_type` parameter.
    out_path = directory.joinpath(f"{audio_file_path.stem}.{output_type}")

    print(f"Current file: '{filename}'")

    with open(audio_file_path, "rb") as audio_file:
        data = service.recognize(
                audio = audio_file,
                speaker_labels = True,
                content_type = "audio/wav",
                inactivity_timeout = -1,
                model = "en-US_NarrowbandModel",
                continuous = True,
            ).get_result()

    print(f"Speech-to-text complete for: '{filename}'")

    # Return data and output path as collection.
    return [data, out_path]


def main():
    print("Running main()...")

    # Default num. workers == min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4)
    n_workers = os.cpu_count() + 2

    # Create generator for all .wav files in folder (and subfolders).
    file_gen = directory.glob("**/*.wav")

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = n_workers) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(process_audio_file, f) for f in file_gen}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            pkg = future.result()
            process_data(*pkg)


def run_script (filename):
    return(process_data(process_audio_file(filename)[0]))
```

#### Shiny code

In server file call run_script function rather than transcribe. Make sure that transcribe.py file is in working directory. Corrected some typo in output$transcript

```
library(shiny)
library(reticulate) # for reading Python code
library(dplyr)
library(stringr) 
library(formattable) # for adding color to tables
library(shinybusy) # for busy bar
library(DT) # for dataTableOutput

use_python("C:/Users/ap396/Anaconda3/python")

ui <- fluidPage(
  add_busy_bar(color = "#5d98ff"),
  fileInput("wavFile", "SELECT .WAV FILE", accept = ".wav",multiple = T),
  uiOutput("downloadData"),
  dataTableOutput("transcript")
  
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # .WAV File Selector ------------------------------------------------------
  
  file <- reactive({
    
    req(input$wavFile) # Require a file before proceeding
    
    files <- input$wavFile # Get file from user input
    file = NULL
    for (i in 1:nrow(files)){
      print(file)
      file = c(file,gsub("\\\\","/",files$datapath[i])) # Access the file path. Convert back slashes to forward slashes.  
    }
    return(file)
  })
  

  # Transcribe and Clean ----------------------------------------------------
  source_python('transcribe.py')
  
  transcript <- reactive({

    dft= data.frame(NULL)
    
    for(j in 1:length(file())){
    t0 = Sys.time()
    transcript <- run_script(file()[j])   #  Transcribe the file  # COMMENT LINE OUT WHEN TESTING NON-TRANSCRIPTION FUNCTIONALITY
    t1 = Sys.time() - t0
    
    transcript$File = j; transcript$Time = t1
    
    dft = rbind(dft,transcript)
    }

    return(dft) # Return the transcript
    
  })
  
  
  # Use a server-side download button ---------------------------------------
  # ...so that the download button only appears after transcription
  
  output$downloadData <- renderUI({
    req(transcript())
    downloadButton("handleDownload","Download CSV")
  })
  
  output$handleDownload <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('Transcript ',Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(transcript(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
  
  # Transcript table --------------------------------------------------------
  
  output$transcript <- renderDataTable({ 
    as.datatable(formattable(
      transcript() %>%
        select(File,
               Time,
               transcript,
               confidence,
               Negative,
               Positive
        ),
      list(Confidence = color_tile('#ffffff','#a2b3c8'),
           Negative = color_tile('#ffffff', '#e74446'),
           Positive = color_tile('#ffffff', "#499650")
      )
    ), rownames = FALSE, options =list(paging = FALSE)
    )
  })
    # END ---------------------------------------------------------------------
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note that shiny download works only in web-browsers so you must open app in a web-browser
[image]

Comment: When i run the UI in shiny, i get the error Error in tag("div", list(...)) : argument is missing, with no default

Comment: There is one extra comma in UI.R code. Delete comma in this line and it should work-dataTableOutput("transcript"),            
     For some reason code worked fine in my system. see the post on this issue- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903347/shiny-ui-r-error-in-tagdiv-list-not-sure-where-error-is

Comment: Now the same error happens when i run the server in R. Also, can you please mention what it means that shiny download works only in web-browsers? How would I have to lunch this from web browswer? currently im just running the code in RStudio

Comment: Additionaly, i notice in the UI, it doesnt show how many seconds it took to transcribe the file as I have in the python app and does it allow to transcribe multiple files in the UI?. Please let me know and I will mark the answer correct

Comment: please respond if you can. the bounty will expire in 2 days

Comment: You can add time for each file by simply adding a line for the time difference in your code. Also, you can add multiple files in input. You have to just specify multiple = T in fileinput and accordingly modify the server script. Regarding download, you can open the app in the browser by simply clicking on open in Browser in your Rstudio shiny app. See the attached shiny app output. You will find the Open in Browser link on top. I have updated the code for adding time and multiple inputs. You can modify it as per your need. Read shiny documentation or google your query before posting. Cheers!!

Comment: To upload multiple files, just select all the files together in browse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I marked it correct and it works. I have one doubt, In the time section, when i transcribe multiple calls, it shows the same time for multiple lines of calls transcribed. I want it to show how many seconds it transcribed for each file and not for every line in a file. How can this be done